# Is there a plugin available to run IIS application on Apache HTTP Server?

Tags: apache2, iis-7.5, ibmhttpserver

My company is looking to set up a Sharepoint server for some of our internal users.  We would like this to be accessible to external users using our current domain (www.companyname.com).  The problem we are having is that www.companyname.com is set up using an IBM HTTP Server (basically Apache) and is based mostly around Java and Websphere.  I was wondering if there was a plug-in available for Apache that would allow my to link up the Sharepoint server (running on IIS) with Apache, much like what is done with Websphere and Apache. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably just use the generic HTTP reverse proxy support in Apache.   If you use this in IHS to front-end sharepoint, it would not be supported by IBM and is technically in violation of the license.

If you receive IHS with an IBM product, it's only licensed and supported when used in direct support of the product it came with.